# How to insert DEFAULT into Postgresql SERIAL column using Scala Java

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, prepared-statement

MySQL will accept NULL to an `auto increment` column and insert the last value. So you could presumably use

(Using the code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805508/631764), where `st` is a `preparedStatement`)

`st.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.NULL)`

I'm trying to figure out how you do the same with Postgresql, where you cannot use `NULL`, but must use `DEFAULT` instead:

```
INSERT INTO serial_table (id) VALUES(NULL)
```

Does something like this exist?

```
st.setDefault(1, java.sql.Types.DEFAULT)
```

Or

```
st.setObject(1, "DEFAULT")
```

I assume I can't just use the string "DEFAULT".

EDIT:

To clarify, this is a testing table defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE serial_table (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

So I can't just skip the column to let Postgresql handle it

```
INSERT INTO serial_table VALUES()
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO serial_table VALUES();
                                        ^
```

Comment: Have you tried null? The null in Java could be interpreted by the Postgres driver as "DEFAULT".

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I did. I'm so used to using MySQL that I ran it that way to start, got the error, then realized "Oh yeah, this is Postgres". Error: `The future returned an exception of type: java.lang.RuntimeException, with message: ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "serial_table" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: "*MySQL will accept NULL to an auto increment column and insert the last value*" - which is a bug in my opinion. You are requesting to store a NULL value, but MySQL silently turns it into something else. What's next? Turning all integer values to 42 because that's "obviously" the correct value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Standard behavior in MySQL, actually. Not a bug. AUTO INCREMENT cannot be null and must be a key. So, I suppose their thinking was, "since NULL is meaningless here, we can use that as a keyword to trigger the default value insertion."

Answer (score 2):

To insert a row consisting *only* of default values you can use:

```
INSERT INTO serial_table DEFAULT VALUES
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm not asking how to insert into Postgres with default values. I'm asking about a way to do that through java/scala. Java has utilities to construct prepared statements and specify values but doesn't have a `DEFAULT`.  It does have a way to pass in a value for `TIMESTAMP` and other such special signifiers (although I have not tried these with prepared statements) so I would think there must be a way to pass `DEFAULT` for `SERIAL` columns in Postgresql. I don't see it in `java.sql.Types` but perhaps there's a library I'm unaware of.

Comment: Obviously it's ridiculous to have a table that has a primary key only. That's the problem. These tables are only for the test suite, to test `CRUD` on different kinds of primary keys. For a table with multiple columns in Postgres you can omit the primary key and Postgres will insert it. But for these dummy tables with only a primary key there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. As in my question `INSERT INTO serial_table VALUES()` doesn't work. And unlike MySQL you can't use `NULL` for primary keys.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: well you can run that statement through Java/Scala. JDBC does not have a way to provide a "DEFAULT value" because `DEFAULT` is a keyword like `SELECT` or `VALUES` which needs to be part of the SQL string. Yes, `INSERT INTO serial_table VALUES()` doesn't work because it's invalid SQL. But the statement in my answer does exactly what you want to achieve with that.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is also a keyword, isn't it? I can see why you wouldn't be able to pass a keyword into a `?` for a parameterized query, but since it seems (perhaps I'm wrong) you can pass a `TIMESTAMP` I thought perhaps you could also somehow pass `DEFAULT` (I was a bit surprised to see `TIMESTAMP` in the `Types`). I've got another solution, but if I could pass `DEFAULT` in, it would simplify the code.

Comment: Drawing from MySQL, I guess `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is really a function. A synonym for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, which also has the `NOW()` synonym. Perhaps Postgres is similar and it would make sense to not be able to pass a SQL function into a parameterized query, but I could also see how it could be implemented. Impossible?

Comment: @ButtleButkus: `current_timestamp` is how the function is defined in the SQL standard. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` or `now()` are non-standard functions. But if you want to pass a value, then provide a column name and use the function in the VALUES clause `insert into serial_table (some_timestamp_column) values (current_timestamp)`

Comment: I'm fairly familiar with basic SQL operations. My question as about java/scala and their prepared statement functionality. I thought perhaps there would be a way to pass a "value" that would be specially handled as not a value but a function or keyword but it seems that's not possible. It seems if you want to pass a DEFAULT then you have to alter the construction of the prepared statement itself, rather than pass a special DEFAULT data type to the `?` and have it specially handled. Been doing SQL for years but new to the Java world.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the primary key:

```
insert into foo (bar) values ("foobar")
```

Will assign the default values to any columns that are not mentioned explicitly.
I am not sure how exactly it is done when you only have one column (the other answer seems to be offering a way to deal with it), but as you said yourself, it's not a sensical use case anyway (as a sidenote, you should not really be writing tests that cover "ridiculous" use cases).

Comment: Perhaps you're right about the tests being ridiculous. Perhaps the real answer is that the tests should have at least one other column. I'm following suggestions for the tests from the owners of the repository. You can create a single-column table, auto increment primary key in MySQL and if you insert `NULL` it will work. And I assume, but haven't tested, that in java you could pass `NULL` as a parameter and it would work. But with Postgres, there's no way, apparently.

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned elsewhere, the behavior you a describing in MySQL looks more like a bug than a feature.

Comment: This will result in an error `"foobar"` refers to a column name. String values need to be enclosed in single quotes in standard SQL (and Postgres), e.g. `'foobar'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OMG! You found a typo!!!!

Comment: @Dima it's well documented in MySQL to use `NULL` as a shorthand for triggering default value for auto increment columns, but MySQL has been moving away from non ANSI tricks like that,. Not sure I'd call it a bug, but perhaps it smells like one.